# How to print percent character?

Tags: android, android-widget

I have this:

```
final String mimeType = "text/html";
final String encoding = "utf-8";

String data = "<img src='blabla.jpg' width='90%' />";
WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);

webview.loadData(summary, mimeType, encoding);
```

And this give me error: "Web page not availible". When I delete "%" it works.

How to print this percent?

Comment: why do you need it as a percent? `width` is a purely pixel attribute.

Comment: I would like to have stretched image on each devices screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the documentation for [loadData](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadData%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

"If the value of the encoding parameter is 'base64', then the data must be encoded as base64. Otherwise, the data must use ASCII encoding for octets inside the range of safe URL characters and use the standard %xx hex encoding of URLs for octets outside that range. For example, '#', '%', '\', '?' should be replaced by %23, %25, %27, %3f respectively. "

so change your data string to be

```
String data = "<img src='blabla.jpg' width='90%25' />";
```